# How to scale an axis within multiplot

Tags: gnuplot, scaling

The error msg:

```
multiplot> plot file1 u ($1/100):2 t "" w lp
           line 0: all points y value undefined!
```

is listed when the script (below) is executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > x.dat <<- "EOF"
100 1
200 2
300 3
EOF

cat | gnuplot <<- "EOF"
file1="x.dat"
set multiplot layout 2,1
stats file1 u 1:2 name "A"
set xrange [A_min_x:A_max_x]
plot file1 u 1:2 t""  w lp
plot file1 u ($1/100):2 t "" w lp
unset multiplot
EOF
```

Comment: Before you continue to ask more questions, please check your earlier questions and accept/upvote the answers (check mark at the top left of the answers) if they solved your problem indicating that the question is answered or clarify if they did not solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `set xrange [A_min_x:A_max_x]` set the xrange to [100:300].  But the second plot command divides x by 100, so all the points would have  x<100 and hence are out of range.  Try `set xrange [0:A_max_x]` instead.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now that you point it out! Thank you Ethan.

Comment: If that solves the problem, then hit the check mark to accept the answer.